# initialize jmockit without -javaagent

Tags: linux, initialization, jmockit, javaagents

I use jmockit and junit to write unit test for a module and run it in a STB. I use jmockit-1.7  because the STB only have java 5.

I got this error when run unit test:
*java.lang.IllegalStateException: Jmockit has not been initialized. Check that your Java 5 VM has been started with -javaagent:jmockit.jar command line option*

but my STB use siege java VM, so it doesn't have -javaagent command line option

I have google, and found a solution from [Running tests with JMockit](https://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r839/trunk/www/tutorial/RunningTests.html)

```
@BeforeClass
public static void Initialize()
{
Mockit.setUpMocks();
}
```

But it's not work. And i have to uses jmockit-0.999.19 to have `Mockit.setUpMocks();`

Could any one help me initialize jmockit without -javaagent and run in java 1.5?

Comment: There is no way to run JMockit on Java 1.5 without the "-javaagent" parameter; you would have to run on Java 1.6 or newer for that.

Comment: Are you sure @Rogério ? Can you help me prove that?

Comment: JDK 1.5 doesn't have the Attach API library, which only appeared in JDK 1.6; JMockit depends on it to dynamically load the Java agent which provides the necessary `java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation` object; when "-javaagent" is used, the Java agent gets loaded by the JVM at startup, so JMockit doesn't need to use the Attach API. These are the *only* two ways that an `Instrumentation` object can be obtained, to the best of my knowledge; and in JDK 1.5, only one of them (the -javaagent way) is available.

Answer (score 0):

3 years ago... 
Update: In the latest version JMockit v1.40 support for JDK6 will be dropped... so use JDK7+ ;-)