# Is there a way to use JMockit without -javaagent with Java 8+ / JUnit 5?

Tags: jmockit

Is there a way to use [`JMockit`](https://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/Introduction.html#runningTests) without -javaagent under Java 8 / Junit 5?  I remember an older version of JMockit had the ability to use the Attach API to dynamically load the javaagent (see [initialize jmockit without -javaagent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29114036/initialize-jmockit-without-javaagent)) but I cannot find that present in the library in v1.49 any longer.

Not all members of my team will know/understand that they need to add the `-javaagent` vm parameter everytime they want to run a unit test from within IntelliJ, so was looking for a way that I can force the JMockit agent to load whenever the test was run without the special configuration.

There is a JMockit plugin for Eclipse which ensures that the javaagent is properly specified, but I could not find anything similar for IntelliJ.

Is there still support in JMockit to load/run without the javaagent?

Comment: A better approach (IMHO) would be to check that the agent is loaded and throw with a descriptive message if not. The message should include the `-javaagent` part like "JMockit requires an agent to run. Start the tests with the -javaagent:jmockit.jar VM argument again."

Comment: @JohannesKuhn that's a great idea; there is a method `Startup.verifyInstrumentation()` that I can use out of the box.  But for someone who has never seen JMockit code before, the exceptionay be a little daunting.  Would have loved there to be a way to bypass the requirement altogether.

Comment: Well, ByteBuddy has a way to install an agent in the current running JVM. If you want to do it yourself, create a new JVM which uses the [attach API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/jdk.attach/module-summary.html) to attach to your JVM.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I also just ran across https://github.com/electronicarts/ea-agent-loader but they say that as of JDK9 using dynamic javaagents are considered bad practice.  I'm still trying to find reference information for that.

Comment: Yeah, that's why you should start a new Java process to do the attach.

Comment: In my current project which uses JMockit, nobody in the team "need to add the -javaagent vm parameter everytime they want to run a unit test from within IntelliJ", because IntelliJ itself takes care of that. We use Maven, but I believe it works the same with Gradle as well. So, what exactly is the problem in your case?